# Java zipcode program

Tags: java, zipcode

I have a home work. I was asked to make a program that will get zipcode from a user input. Then I'm gonna use the first digit only to determine the location. My instructor told me that the data type to be used is int. can you pls help me? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing characters with *integers*, so currently you're comparing them with the control characters U+0003 and U+0004 - you want to compare them with *characters* representing the digits:

```
if (zipCode.charAt(0) <= '3')
...
if (zipCode.charAt(0) >= '4')
    if (zipCode.charAt(0) <= '6')
```

(You might consider using a switch statement too...)

I've no idea whether this is correct in terms of what zip codes mean, but that's the immediate problem with your code.